# Publish a acknowledgement to a queue and sent a message to another queue

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq

I need to check the the string legth first. If the string length is greater that 3 means, the acknowledgement sends to one queue. If the string length is lesser than one queue means (len(str)<3), the string will sends to another queue using python code

```
Add_Update_Queue ='Test_Queue' 
Delete_queue ='Testing_Queue' 
message="123" 
add=channel.basic_publish(exchange='ExchangePreParserPostingData',routing_key='A‌​ddPreParserPosting', body=message) 
x=len(message) 
print x 
def validate(self, message): 
    if len(message)<5: 
    self.channel.basic_consume(queue=Delete_queue,no_ack=True) 

def consume(self): 
    self.channel.basic_consume(self.validate, queue=Settings.Add_Update_Queue, no_ack=True) 
    self.channel.start_consuming() 

if name == 'main': 
    pos.validate(message) 
    pos.consume()
```

Comment: So what have you already done and what is your question?

Comment: I just publish a message to a queue. That works fine. I need to compare the string length, if it is greater than 3 means, the acknowledgement will be send to a separate queue. If the string length is lesser than 3 means, that string will send to another separate queue

Comment: You have to use `ìf`-statement.

Comment: Yes @Alex.S , i have used if statement but ack does not send to the separate queue

Comment: My problem is how to publish an acknowledgement to a Queue

Comment: If you provide us with your code, you might get more useful answers.

Comment: Add_Update_Queue ='Test_Queue'
Delete_queue ='Testing_Queue'
message="123"
add=channel.basic_publish(exchange='ExchangePreParserPostingData',routing_key='AddPreParserPosting',
                          body=message)
x=len(message)
print x

def validate(self, message):
 if len(message)<5:
  self.channel.basic_consume(queue=Delete_queue,no_ack=True)
def consume(self):
      self.channel.basic_consume(self.validate, queue=Settings.Add_Update_Queue, no_ack=True)
      self.channel.start_consuming()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pos.validate(message)
    pos.consume()

Comment: I added your code to your question. Check if I correctly formatted it. It is not a good idea to publish your code the way you have done it.

Comment: yes, that is correctly formatted. Am sorry to publish the code that way @Alex S

Comment: You have to approve the edit, otherwise no one else can see it.

Comment: Is there any possibility to send a consumed message from one queue to another queue